# python script will not be executed

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I have following script

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import cgi
import sys



def header():

  header = """
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <html>
    <body bgcolor="#B7B7B7">
    """
  print header

def footer():
  footer = """
    </body>
    </html>
    """


def main():
  try:
    header()
    footer()
  except:
    print "<!-- --><hr><h1>Oops. An error occured.</h1>"
    cgi.print_exception()

main()
```

This script is called from another script - problem is that is not working. The browser just simply write whole code as plain text beside HTML tags:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import os 
import cgi 
import sys 

def header(): 
    header = """ """ 
    print header 

def footer(): 
    footer = """ """ 

def main(): 
    try: 
        header() 
        footer() 
    except: 
        print "Oops. An error occured." 
        cgi.print_exception() 

main()
```

I checked the apache error log, there is nothing about it.

I tried chmod 777, still the same

this is how my config.py looks like:

```
<Directory "{1}">
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Python version is 2.7

Do you have any idea how to run this script? Thanks a lot!

Comment: calling from another script.. how are you doing that?  Is it another python script?

Comment: Sorry i cannot see were you try to call the first script in the second script. Could you elaborate?

Comment: -yes,it is another python script, classic <Form action =thisscript.py">
-Salo, sorry for bad post, im newbie here and I dont know exactly how posts shoud looks like..the second "script" is not code, its just output what I get when I call first..thats why I dont use code styling, but i have been suggested to fix it this way :) Once again sorry

Answer (score 0):

What output are you expecting from running this script (which I agree with ergonaut) is not clear how you are doing it.

Running the script independently, it works, but it does not have any natural output...so potentially it is working but you have no means of verifying.

Comment: This script is only smal part of normal one, I dont want paste here huge code, I just tried to minimalize it as much as possible and keep the bad output :)
If I would run this script which I wrote above,(the first one), I would expect nothing,because it has nothing to do. However, my browser show me the second script, so it is not executed but only written as a plain text beside HTML tags. Sorry for tortuos post :(

Answer (score 0):

Only other suggestions are calling the python module and breakpointing to see where it fails from an ide (e.g. eclipse). Also capturing logging error may help, but I presume you have tried both of those.

Comment: thanks, i will try. I have checked the logs but I was not debugging yet. Funny thing is that it is not working on the one from three servers I have..maybe it is somehow server issue, but I cant see any, cos there are running a hundred of scripts and this is only one which is bad. But thank for help anyway :))